# Using Object DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, objectdatasource

I'm trying to use an ObjectBindingSource to bind  data to a gridview. The data is present in the view as a subclass as the controller, in the form of a model.

```
var _controller = new DataController(param1, param2);
```

you would access it in this manner

```
foreach(var Variable in _controller.DataModel.Cars)
<%: Car.Name %> ...
```

How can I use this DataModel.Cars as the source for the Object binding source?

I currently have

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"  
        TypeName="Choices.ChoiceService.ChoiceCollection"  
        DataObjectTypeName="Choices.ChoiceService.ChoiceObject" 
        InsertMethod="Add" SelectMethod="AsReadOnly"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a Select Method on DataController say GetCars this way you would do:

```
public class DataController
{
   public IEnumerable<Car> GetCars(int param1, int param2)
   {
      return this.DataModel.Cars;
   }
}
```

and then you would use:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"  
        TypeName="Choices.ChoiceService.DataController"  
        DataObjectTypeName="Choices.ChoiceService.Car" 
         SelectMethod="GetCars">
       <SelectParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter Name="param1" SessionField="param1" />
          <asp:SessionParameter Name="param2" SessionField="param2" />
       </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

You then set the session on the codebehind witht:

```
Session["param1"] = 12;
Session["param2"] = 13;
```

Note:There are much better ways to do this, using the session like this is really ugly, this is only an example. You probably can pick a better one from the following 
list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz.aspx

Alternatively you can use the OnDataBinding event of the ObjectDataSource to programatically set the parameters directly on the ObjectDataSource instance.

Comment: Yes, you have some options here...check this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt50s8kz.aspx